# Replace Text with Condition (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

How to replace text with condition in VB.Net

```
ItemNumber = "2.4.1.2.1" become PartNumber = "02-04-01-02" 
ItemNumber = "22.4.1.20.10" become PartNumber "22-04-01-20"
ItemNumber = "1.1" become PartNumber "01"
```

Thanks @Andrew. I'm try for modified your code. Here's the code :

```
Dim ItemNumber As String = "22.4.1.20.100.5"
Dim PartNumbers As String() = ItemNumber.Split(New Char() {"."c})
Dim x As Integer = PartNumbers.Length - 1
Dim myRange = PartNumbers.Take(x).Select(Function(a) a.PadLeft(2, "0"c))
Dim PartNumber = String.Join("-", myRange)
Console.WriteLine(PartNumber)
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

The other way of thinking of it is that you want the first four parts, and you want those parts left-padded with zeros:

```
Dim partNumber = String.Join("-", itemNumber.Split("."c).Take(4).Select(Function(a) a.PadLeft(2, "0"c)))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Sorry for not clear question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
Dim ItemNumber As String = "22.4.1.20.10"
Dim ItemsNumber() As String = ItemNumber.Split("."c)
ReDim Preserve ItemsNumber(ItemsNumber.Length - 2)

For numberIndex As Integer = 0 To ItemsNumber.Length - 1
    ItemsNumber(numberIndex) = ItemsNumber(numberIndex).PadLeft(2, "0")
Next

Dim PartNumber As String = Strings.Join(ItemsNumber, "-")

'22.4.1.20.10   -->  22-04-01-20
'2.4.1.2.1      -->  02-04-01-02
'22.4.1.20.10.5 -->  22-04-01-20-10
```